# import csv file and return two lists for string and integer respectively without csv module in python

Tags: python

I have a list of CSV data like below:

```
Jim     57      83  55  78
John        98  91  80  
Michael 61      88  80  60
Harry   92      58  50  57
James   51      97  52  53
```

and I want to return as without importing CSV module, the blank value I want to print None and double quote around name and no quote around integers:

```
[("Jim",57,None,83,55,78), ("John",None,98,91,80,None), ("Michael",61,None,88,80,60)]....
```

I have tried some code:

```
def student_mark(studentfile):
     f = open (studentfile, 'r')
     list = []
     for line in f: 
         list.append(tuple(line.strip().split(',')))
     print (list)

studentfile = " users/.../units.csv"
student_mark(studentfile)
```

But it now results as:

```
[('Jim','57','','83','55','78'), ('John','','98','91','80',''), ('Michael','61','','88','80','60')
```

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Do you have pandas installed ?

Comment: The first purpose for this task is to decode without importing any module

Comment: So you want to use the Python language but none of the modules that it provides?

Comment: Yes Stephen, if you can help

Comment: What is the csv delimiter? Is it a tab? If not you don't have a csv file. It's ok though, you can use slices.

Comment: Hi Maric, it is comma delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the code that I rebuilt:

```
filepath = r'C:\Users\kudangren\Desktop\testfile\testfile.csv'


def CleanData(line):

    listline = []
    for i in line:
        if i.isdigit():
            listline.append(int(i))
        elif i == '':
            i = 'None'
            listline.append(i)
        else:
            listline.append(i)
    return tuple(listline)


def student_mark(studentfile):
    with open(studentfile,'r') as csvfile:
        read = csvfile.read()
        resultlist = []
        for line in read.split('\n'):
            result=CleanData(line.split(','))
            resultlist.append(result)

        print(resultlist)


student_mark(filepath)
```

results of execution：

```
[('Jim', 57, 'None', 83, 55, 78), ('John', 'None', 98, 91, 80, 'None'), ('Michael', 61, 'None', 88, 80, 60), ('Harry', 92, 'None', 58, 50, 57), ('James', 51, 'None', 97, 52, 53)]
```

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the use of str.isdigit (). Judge whether the string is numeric, can this answer help you?

```
import csv


filepath = r'C:\Users\kudangren\Desktop\testfile\testfile.csv'


def CleanData(line):
    listline = []
    for i in line:
        if i.isdigit():
            listline.append(int(i))
        elif i == '':
            i = 'None'
            listline.append(i)
        else:
            listline.append(i)
    return tuple(listline)


def student_mark(studentfile):
    with open(studentfile,'r') as csvfile:
        read = csv.reader(csvfile)
        resultlist = []
        for line in read:
            resultline=CleanData(line)
            resultlist.append(resultline)
        print(resultlist)

student_mark(filepath)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LK5F.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F10X6.png)

Comment: Hi Jia, thanks for help. But I would like the answer without importing CSV module. Do you have it?

Comment: Hi Jia, it can read by CSV module, in fact it is .csv file. But I would like to decode the string and integer by hand. That's why I stuck there